# Showing a matrix is 1-1

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism, module-isomorphism

How do I show below is 1-1. I also know the natural basis is $R^2$[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I’m not sure where to even start. I think I’d need to change $R^2$ into a 2x2 matrix though

Comment: Why do you want to calculate $R^2$? (I'm assuming you mean $R=R_{\pi/3}$) The question is about $R$, isn't it?

Comment: You need to show the invertibility of $R_{\pi/3}$. The easiest way would be to calculate the determinant of $R_{\pi/3}$.

Comment: Show that the determinant is not zero.

Comment: I added the full question so I would only need to use the given matrix and show the determinate isn’t zero

Comment: [This question is the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3513497/81360), one of these should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It’s a different question regarding the same topic I deleted the other one

Comment: Brilliant I get that the determinant is 1 so does that mean it’s 1-1

Comment: Hi guys how would I show this is a linear transformation?