# Linear transformation of a 2x2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a 2x2 matrix and what to show it’s a linear transformations how do I start? 
Any tips or suggestions would be great

Answer (score 3):

Apply the transformation to a vector by writing the vector as a 2-element column vector and multiplying Av to give a column vector. Then see what happens to the sum of column vectors and to a column vector multiplied by a scalar.

Comment: This link has the image of the question I want to answer could you take a look please I’m really finding it hard. Many thanks https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3513938/654644